# Pyspark Display not showing chart in Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following line of code:

```
display(df2.groupBy("TransactionDate").sum("Amount").orderBy("TransactionDate"))
```

Which according to this document:
https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/visualizations/index.html#visualizations-in-python

Should give me a chart in Jupyter. Instead I get the following output:

```
DataFrame[TransactionDate: timestamp, sum(Amount): double]
```

How come?

Comment: Why not `df2.groupBy("TransactionDate").sum("Amount").orderBy("TransactionDate").show()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which according to this document
>   ...
>   Should give me a chart in Jupyter.

It should not. `display` is a feature of a proprietary Databricks platform, not feature of Spark, so unless you use their notebook flavor (based on Zeppelin not Jupyter), it won't be available for you.